# Figuring out how to change function to php 7?

Tags: php

i was changing a function from php 5.2 to php 7.got stuck however,not familiar with php 7

```
function custom_autoloader($className) //$className inside spl function
{
if (file_exists(CORE_ROOT . '/includes/' . lcfirst($className) .    '.  class.php'))
{  
    spl_autoload_register('custom_autoloader')


    //require_once(CORE_ROOT . '/includes/' . lcfirst($className) . '.class.php');
}
});
```

Comment: well it is backward compatible so there is no reason,

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7.1 will still run older code, but you could make the scalar type hints and return types like this. The void return type was [merged](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1576) last year.

```
function custom_autoloader(string $className) : void
{
    if (file_exists(CORE_ROOT . '/includes/' . 
                    lcfirst($className) . '.class.php')) {  
       spl_autoload_register('custom_autoloader')

    }
});
```